# version control for open office

Tags: openoffice, version-control

I know open office files are just zip of text (plus images), so I'm temped to use my favorite version control system to version them, but I'll need some hooks to zip/unzip etc.

Somebody must have already done this and/or there must be a better way: any suggestions?

Note: I am a programmer and I very much prefer using a command line tool as opposed to some graphical thing. Example of what I mean: if I removed a comma in a 100+ slides presentation, I want a line long diff, which shows just that comma and the slide number. I don't want to sift through the whole presentation looking for that comma striked somewhere (and always wondering if I missed anything else)

Answer (score 1):

[OOoSVN](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/OOoSVN)

> A project to provide change control
>   for OpenOffice.org documents
>   (OpenDocument and *.sx*) via
>   subversion. Transparently checks in
>   internal changes in files and allows
>   users to recover any previous version,
>   view logs and compare with older
>   versions. Works under Unix/Linux and
>   Mac OSX.

Comment: Are you actually using it "in production"? It was forked in 2008 and abandoned. The forked project (odfsvn) is an inactive project as well.

Comment: @Davide No...but I show activity within the src of OOoSVN until 2/2010...http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooosvn/files/OOoSVN/

Comment: I tested current version (i.e. v0.4) and it is not a production ready stuff. For example you can't even write your own commit message, but everything gets an useless, automated "Commit x" message. I'd rater unzip the open office files and do my stuff myself.

Comment: @Davide It's OSS; jump in and contribute; then others can benefit.